# ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

This is my controller for **PostController**:

```
public function getAllPosts() {
    $posts = Posts::all();

    /*foreach ($posts as $post){

        /* $username = $post->user->name;
        //do something with $username

    }*/

    return View::make('welcome', compact('posts'));
    //here the $detailed_posts can be defined in the 'do something' above
}
```

This is my code for **User Model** Eloquent

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'user';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

The **Post Model** Eloquent

```
class Posts extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = array('title, image, text, user_id');
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
```

This is my **welcome.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<div class="col-sm-7">
<hr>
<h2>{{ $post->title}}</h2>
<h5>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Post by {{$post->user->username}}, Sep 27, 2015.
</h5>
@endforeach
```

I'm getting error in `{{$post->user->username}}`

I already tried with `{{$post->user['username']}}` this works but don't show me any value of user.

Can anybody help me in this process?

Comment: the error statement is very clear and as you already have mentioned $post->user['username'] works. i assume here $post->user returns you an array instead of an object. just check what do you get by var_dump($post->user);

Comment: just check that all posts have a user_id, if at least one does not you will get this error (assuming the relationship works)

Comment: not familiar with eloquent but still a suggestion to try and change the user relation in post model: in place of belongsTo - try hasOne

Comment: what do you get if you dd($post->user) ?

Comment: doing dd($post->user) i´m getting null

Comment: {{dd($post->user)}}

Comment: just `dd($posts)` before your return statement in your controller and if you get any results then try  `dd($posts[0]->user)` to check if there is a relation..

Comment: @Onix i´m getting null in the screen

Comment: with dd($posts)?

Comment: With dd($posts[0]->user)

Comment: #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "title" => "Websites created"
        "text" => "Websites created"
        "image" => "Websites created"
        "User_id" => 1
      ] But i dont see the username in the array

Comment: What happens if you change         return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
 to just         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

Comment: User_id is capitalize..... it should be user_id,, fix your database

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is         `return $this->belongsTo('App\User','User_id');`

AND not

```
 return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
```